# Azure PII minimumPrecision Filter

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, pii

I am trying to filter results by minimum precision to exclude any PII names that are too low in confidence (.5) using python and Azures PII cognitive service.

```
response=client.recognize_pii_entities(documents,language="en",categories_filter=['Person'], minimumPrecision=[.8])
```

the `request()` gets an unexpected key word argument for `"minimumPrecision"`

`categories_filter` was different from the `piiCategories` that the azure documentation says to use and that is the functional parameter so I am wondering if `minimumPrecision` is also actually supposed to be different, but I cannot find it in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client library does not support a `minimumPrecision` parameter. The REST API does not either. Can you share the Azure documentation which shows usage of this parameter?

You should be able to filter the entity results on the `confidence_score` for the same effect:

```
response = client.recognize_pii_entities(documents, language="en", categories_filter=['Person'])
results = [entity for entity in res.entities for res in result if entity.confidence_score > 0.8]
```

Comment: that will have to do then, thank you. here is the link tot he docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-pii-detection

Comment: Ah I see. It looks like this documentation is showing PII detection as a Cognitive Search skill. Azure Cognitive Search is accessed through a different client library. You could look at the azure-search-documents package if you want support for minimumPrecision. Although since Search is using the Language service anyway, you'll get the same results as you have now with above code.